# Selenium runs as scheduled task on Windows Server

Tags: c#, selenium

We have an application where we use the Selenium test framework. The application runs on Windows Server 2012 and runs regularly through Windows Task Scheduler. I connect to the server through Remote Desktop.

The problem occurs when I set in the scheduled task set-up option "Run whether user is logged on or not". My application starts to run properly with this javascript code but then it ends immediately with error exception - it is marked on the line below. If I start the application normally, everything works fine. Unfortunately, I need to make an application which can run even when no one is logged on.  Hasn´t anyone already met with this problem?

This is my code:

```
public Bitmap MakeBitmap(Uri url)
{
    driver = MakeFirefoxDriver();
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url.AbsoluteUri);

    // In this command, an exception occurs.
    driver.ExecuteScript("document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden'")

    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(SleepTime));
    var screenshot = driver.GetScreenshot();
    return new Bitmap(Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(screenshot.AsByteArray)));
}

private FirefoxDriver MakeFirefoxDriver() 
{
    var profile = new FirefoxProfile { EnableNativeEvents = true };
    var capabilityValue = new List<string> { "-width", "500", "-height", "340" };
    var capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Firefox();
    capabilities.SetCapability("initial", capabilityValue);
    capabilities.SetCapability(FirefoxDriver.ProfileCapabilityName, profile);
    return new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
}
```

Exception looks like this:

```
Exception log: No response from server for url http://localhost:7062/hub/session/......
StackTrace: at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest
request) at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String
driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters) at ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Task Scheduler on Windows 7, hopefully it's the same.  In the scheduler, on the General tab, click "Run whether the user is logged on or not".  With this setting, you will need to enter your password whenever you save the properties.
When it runs nothing will appear on the screen.  I have read on these forums that, running in this mode, if you try to grab an image it will be blank.